# Помогите собрать UDP (datagram) пакет

Tags: java, udp

Есть ядро сервера, у него есть `datagram` сокет по которому приходит подобная информация:
[image: HEX] [HEX](https://pastebin.com/j4tb7f78), [ASCII](https://pastebin.com/CfN6QvZ9), [UTF-8](https://pastebin.com/MhJM9f3T).

Проблема в том, что код там запутан (не понятен мне), и я не могу понять, что да как и от куда.

[ВОТ](https://yivesmirror.com/files/spigot/spigot-1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1648.jar) JAR файл, всего ядра. И класс в котором генерируются пакеты, это `RemoteStatusListener`, он находится в пакете `net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1`. 
[Вот](https://pastebin.com/ziryQYfs) этот класс.

Вот начало пакета, самое непонятное, #4 пакет всё ясно, и я знаю, что от куда взять, но вот начало, без понятия, что это за символы и т.д. Как мне сделать точно такой же пакет, не зависимо от этого класса `RemoteStatusListener`.